# Can't installing Umbraco on LocalMachine

Tags: umbraco, webmatrix

I want install Umbraco 5.0 on WebMatrix.
But i am sends back to me after the third step, What's Problem ?

Answer (score 1):

your question is too general,

download the release from the codeproject site, you have to simply extract it into a folder and go to the webmatrix, open website from folder and it will work fine, if you are using IIS to deploy your site then it only happens that there are no permissions of read/write for the folder of the site in Application Pool,

Comment: okey i doing you say but now step 3 database during % 35 remain what's problem ? i am correct set connection string.

Comment: can you post your connection string...?